# How to read Taxi Meter data from Serial to USB

Tags: android, serial-port, usb, meter

Hey I need to read **Taxi Meter** Data from serial port using Android. Tell me some possible ways to implement it...

I need to get Amount, Start time, End time, Waiting time etc from meter and display it in Android text view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually up to the taxi meter device. Android can just supply you with USB support (Host or Accessory mode). You can find the relevant documentation here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/index.html

Once obtained a working communication channel, it is up to the taxi meter device to define which data are made available and how they can be read/used. You will need the taxi meter documentation for this (or you will have to do a lot of reverse engineering...).

Displaying the data in a view is a task in itself. You will have to read the documentation, design the desired view and populate it with your data. Try to start here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/index.html